# Teechart Data Editing disable

Tags: activex, teechart

Can anyone let me know how we can restrict the user to change the data for for series or whether we can disable it.

Thanks
Akshay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given such a generic answer and not knowing the nature of your applications we can't provide a specific answer. However, as a general rule of thumb, don't grant users access to the chart editor nor any functionality that would allow them to use data.

Also, this has been implemented for next TeeChart VCL/FMX release: http://bugs.teechart.net/show_bug.cgi?id=484#c1

This has<strike>n't</strike> been implemented for the ActiveX version <strike>though</strike> now, build 2014.0.0.1 from 19th June. <strike>We will add it for the next maintenance release.</strike> It should be something like this:

```
TeeEditor1.Options.DataEditing = False
```

Other <strike>Current</strike> alternatives are:

1. You can use the ChartGrid component and set it to read-only: `ChartGrid1.ReadOnly = True`
2. Hiding Data tab in TeeEditor: `TeeEditor1.ShowPages.SeriesData = False`

Comment: Actually user can change the remaining property of Editting. The requirement is that data which is shown Data Tab should be read only not editable

Comment: @AkshayBhalla this is not possible for now. I have added it as a feature request for future versions: http://bugs.teechart.net/show_bug.cgi?id=484. In the meantime you could use a read-only grid to display data.

Comment: is there any way we can disable data tab from the Editing

Comment: @AkshayBhalla you can only choose to hide data tab in the editor as shown in the "All Features\Welcome!\Components\Chart Editor\Chart Editor dialog" example at the new features demo, available at TeeChart's program group.

Comment: @AkshayBhalla this feature has now been implemented for future releases: http://bugs.teechart.net/show_bug.cgi?id=484#c1

Comment: Hi till when can we except the release

Comment: @AkshayBhalla Current version was published less than 3 weeks ago. No date has been established yet for the next version. Please be aware at the Steema Software communication channels: website, forums, facebook, twitter, newsletter, etc. It will be announced there.

Comment: Hi, I have taken the latest version of Teechart ActiveX released on 9th April Can you please let me know how the data editing can be disabled in the TeeEditor Data window.

Comment: @AkshayBhalla it's not available in current ActiveX version. It will be added for the next maintenance release. I have updated my reply with some alternatives.

Comment: @AkshayBhalla the ActiveX version from 19th June (v2014.0.0.1) supports this: `TeeEditor1.Options.EditData = False`